# find and copy all images in directory using terminal linux mint, trying to understand syntax

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, find, linux-mint

OS Linux Mint

Like the title says finally I would like to find and copy all images in a directory.

I found:

**find all jpg (or JPG) files in a directory and copy them into the folder /home/joachim/neu2:**

```
find . -iname \*.jpg -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 cp -v {} /home/joachim/neu2
```

and

**find all image files in a direcotry:**

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'
```

My problem is first of all, I don't really understand the syntax. Could someone explain the code?

And secondly can someone connect the two codes for generating a code that does what I want ;)

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, understand that the pipe "|" links commands piping the output of the first into the second as an argument. Your two shell codes both pipe output of the find command into other commands (grep and xargs). Let's look at those commands one after another:

**First command: find**

find is a program to "search for files in a directory hierarchy" (that is the explanation from find's man page). The syntax is (in this case)

```
find <search directory> <search pattern> <action>
```

In both cases the search directory is . (that is the current directory). Note that it does not just search the current directory but all its subdirectories as well (the directory hierarchy).

The search pattern accepts options -name (meaning it searches for files the name of which matches the pattern given as an argument to this option) or -iname (same as name but case insensitive) among others.

The action pattern may be -print0 (print the exact filename including its position in the given search directory, i.e. the relative or absolute path to the file) or -exec (execute the given command on the file(s), the command is to be ended with ";" and every instance of "{}" is replaced by the filename).

That is, the first shell code (first part, left of the pipe)

```
find . -iname \*.jpg -print0
```

searches all files with ending ".jpg" in the current directory hierarchy and prints their paths and names. The second one (first part)

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \;
```

finds all files in the current directory hierarchy and executes

```
file <filename>
```

on them. File is another command that determines and prints the file type (have a look at the man page for details, man file).

**Second command: xargs**

xargs is a command that "builds and exectues command lines from standard input" (man xargs), i.e. from the find output that is piped into xargs. The command that it builds and executes is in this case

```
cp -v {} /home/joachim/neu2"
```

Option -I{} defines the replacement string, i.e. every instance of {} in the command is to be replaced by the input it gets from file (that is, the filenames). Option -0 defines that input items are not terminated (seperated) by whitespace or newlines but only by a null character. This seems to be necessary when using and the standard way to deal with find output as xargs input.

The command that is built and executed is then of course the copy command with option -v (verbose) and it copies each of the filenames it gets from find to the directory.

**Third command: grep**

grep filters its input giving only those lines or strings that match a particular output pattern. Option -o tells grep to print only the matching string, not the entire line (see man grep), -P tells it to interpret the following pattern as a perl regexp pattern. In perl regex, ^ is the start of the line, .+ is any arbitrary string, this arbitrary should then be followed by a colon, a space, a number of alphanumeric characters (in perl regex denoted \w+) a space and the string "image". Essentially this grep command filters the file output to only output the filenames that are image files. (Read about perl regex's for instance here: http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/matching.html )

**The command you actually wanted**

Now what you want to do is (1) take the output of the second shell command (which lists the image files), (2) bring it into the appropriate form and (3) pipe it into the xargs command from the first shell command line (which then builds and executes the copy command you wanted). So this time we have a three (actually four) stage shell command with two pipes. Not a problem. We already have stages (1) and (3) (though in stage (3) we need to leave out the -0 option because the input is not find output any more; we need it to treat newlines as item seperators).

Stage (2) is still missing. I suggest using the cut command for this. cut changes strings py splitting them into different fields (seperated by a delimiter character in the original string) that can then be rearranged. I will choose ":" as the delimiter character (this ends the filename in the grep output, option -d':') and tell it to give us just the first field (option -f1, essentialls: print only the filename, not the part that comes after the ":"), i.e. stage (2) would then be

```
cut -d':' -f1
```

And the entire command you wanted will then be:

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image' | cut -d':' -f1 | xargs -I{} cp -v {} /home/joachim/neu2
```

Note that you can find all the man pages for instance here: http://www.linuxmanpages.com

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Your answer contains so much information that really helps me understanding the whole thing much better.

Comment: And it is crazy how much one has to know for understanding the commands.

Comment: When you say

"...or -exec (execute the given command on the file(s), the command is to be ended with ";"... "

do you actually mean \;  or why is there a \ ?

Comment: The \ is an escape character which is there in order to avoid the ; being expanded by the shell (in that case the shell would interpret it not as part of the find command but as separating two commands that are to be executed sequentially)

Comment: Just wanted to say: Great detailed answer that prompted me to log in, just so that I could upvote you.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. How could I use this to save the image along with its current file structure to the new directory?

Comment: @Ryan I do not see why not. You would just have to create the directories before copying the images. There may or may not be a way to use more pipes to integrate that into this one-line command. But it is generally held that readability counts. As a consequence, I would strongly suggest to write a bash script with a bit more structure instead. In any case, this would be a separate question.

Comment: You said iname is case sensitive .. but the manual says: -iname pattern
              Like -name, but the match is **case insensitive**.  For example, the patterns `fo*' and `F??' match the file names `Foo', `FOO', `foo', `fOo', etc.   The pattern `*foo*` will also match a file called '.foobar'.

Comment: @MikeKormendy: Yeah, that was a simple mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a command only using awk that does the job as well:

```
find . -name '*' -exec file {} \; | 
awk '{
    if ($3=="image"){
        print substr($1, 0, length($1)-1);
        system("cp " substr($1, 0, length($1)-1) " /home/joachim/neu2" )
    }   
}'
```

the substr($1, 0, length($1)-1) is needed because in first column file returns name;

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is really good. but it could take longer if it a huge directory.
here is a shorter version of it , if you already know your file extension

```
 find . -name \*.jpg | cut -d':' -f1 | xargs -I{} cp --parents -v {} ~/testimage/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one which works like a charm.
It adds the EPOCH time to prevent overwriting files with the same name.

```
cd /media/myhome/'Local station'/
find . -path ./jpg -prune -o -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
for file do
   newname="${file##*/}"
   newname="${newname%.jpg}"
   mv -T -- "$file" "/media/myhome/Local station/jpg/$newname-$(date +%s).jpg"
done
' find-sh {} +
cd  ~/
```

It's been designed by Kamil in [this post here](https://superuser.com/questions/1640649/how-can-i-modify-path-coming-from-in-find-exec/1640808#1640808).

Answer (score 0):

Find a specific type file from a directory:

```
find /home/user/find/data/ -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'
```

Copy specific type of file from one directory to another directory:

```
find /home/user/find/data/ -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image' | cut -d':' -f1 | xargs -I{} cp -v {} /home/user/copy/data/
```